# Peer node is not syncing all blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, nodes

I'm running a private network with two nodes (geth 1.8.3-stable on macOS 10.13.3). Node 1 mined 422 blocks:

Node 1:

```
> eth.blockNumber
422
```

Node 2 is a peer of Node 1 but Node 2 only has the first 384 blocks:

Node 2:

```
> eth.blockNumber
384
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 384,
  highestBlock: 422,
  knownStates: 2,
  pulledStates: 2,
  startingBlock: 384
}
```

So Node 2 is missing 38 blocks. I've tried restarting both nodes several times to no avail.

Initially, I made the nodes peers manually (via `admin.addPeer()`) but after reading the [private network](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network) documentation I tried using the `--bootnodes` argument instead: same result.

---

Node 1 startup:

`$ geth --datadir /Users/x/ethereum/first/ console --networkid 1234 --nodiscover`

Node 2 startup:

`$ geth --datadir /Users/x/ethereum/first-1a/ console --networkid 1234 --nodiscover --port 30304`

or

`$ geth --datadir /Users/x/ethereum/first-1a/ console --networkid 1234 --nodiscover --bootnodes "enode://a94...2c3@[::]:30303?discport=0" --port 30304`

Comment: Which consensus algorithm are you using? PoW or Clique (PoA)?

Comment: I believe PoW (I'm running a new geth installation and haven't changed any of the defaults).